# supportedInterfaceOrientations() error in Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I just migrated a project to Swift 2.0 and this previously working code now produces an error:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {  
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue) | Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)  
    }
```

The error indicates the return types are incorrect but I've tried several ways of returning this with no luck.

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'Int' to return type 'UIInterfaceOrientationMask'

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As of Swift 2.0, bit masking is replaced by using arrays of mask values, your code should now read:

```
 override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return [.Portrait, .PortraitUpsideDown]
}
```

Comment: That worked great thanks! All of the errors I'm getting after migrating are bit mask related so that's really useful info to have.

Comment: awesome, can you accept the answer as correct then?

Comment: Sure, still have to wait a couple of minutes before it'll let me accept.

Comment: If you can help with this similar issue I'd really appreciate it! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32506336/unary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-an-operand-of-type-mytype

Comment: And in Swift 3?

Comment: It's the same as swift 2.

Answer (score 5):

There is an update of supportedInterfaceOrientations for Swift 3.0:

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {  
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.portrait  
}
```

And function for autorotating:

```
override var shouldAutorotate: Bool {
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Danny Bravo's answer is correct, but I wanted to point out one other thing. As of Swift 2.0, `UIInterfaceOrientationMask` (and most other bitmask types) conform to [`OptionSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_OptionSetType_Protocol/index.html), which conforms to [`AlgebraSetType`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SetAlgebraType_Protocol/index.html), meaning you can do all kinds of operations on those like `union`, `intersect`, etc.

For example, in Swift 1.2, code like this:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    var orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    if FeatureManager.hasLandscape() {
        orientations |= UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape
    }

    return Int(orientations.rawValue)
}
```

...would be more like this in Swift 2.0:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    var orientations = UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait
    if FeatureManager.hasLandscape() {
        orientations.insert( UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Landscape )
    }

    return orientations
}
```

Comment: Just curious: did this quirky awesomeness carry forward to Swift 3, or did it change again? Thanks!