# Unary operator '~' cannot be applied to an operand of type 'MyType'

Tags: ios, swift

I have some code that has broken since migrating to Swift 2.0. I now get the error in the title of the question.

```
message.flags = NSNumber(integer:(MCOMessageFlag(rawValue: message.flags.integerValue).intersect(~MCOMessageFlag.Seen)).rawValue)
```

MyType is a bitmask. Any idea what has changed in Swift to make this now produce an error?

Edit:

```
    typedef NS_OPTIONS(NSInteger, MCOMessageFlag) {
    MCOMessageFlagNone          = 0,
    /** Seen/Read flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagSeen          = 1 << 0,
    /** Replied/Answered flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagAnswered      = 1 << 1,
    /** Flagged/Starred flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagFlagged       = 1 << 2,
    /** Deleted flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagDeleted       = 1 << 3,
    /** Draft flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagDraft         = 1 << 4,
    /** $MDNSent flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagMDNSent       = 1 << 5,
    /** $Forwarded flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagForwarded     = 1 << 6,
    /** $SubmitPending flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagSubmitPending = 1 << 7,
    /** $Submitted flag.*/
    MCOMessageFlagSubmitted     = 1 << 8,
};
```

Comment: can you post the code for MyType?

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm not understanding your usage of `~MyType.Value` and where the .intersect() function comes from. Can you describe the error you're getting?

Comment: Sorry. MyType.Value is MCOMessageFlag.Seen for example. The error is: 'Unary operator ~ cannot be applied to an operand of type MCOMessageFlag.' .intersect() is a function from Swift OptionSetType. The code worked great until I migrated and it seems to be a bit mask related issue again.

Comment: Is MyType the same as MCOMessageFlag? What is myObject and myObject.prop? Please show a complete self-contained example.

Comment: The problem has got to do with the operator "~". I don't believe it's a valid operator in swift and to be honest I've never really used it in Obj-C, so I'm not even sure what it does!

Comment: @DannyBravo No problem thanks. I've put the full code up now Martin.

Comment: @DannyBravo It's [the bitwise not operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html), as [it is in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C) and Objective C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you just want to end up with an integer anyway:

```
myObject.prop = NSNumber(integer:
    myObject.prop.integerValue & ~MCOMessageFlag.Seen.rawValue)
```

Or maybe this would be clearer for your specific case:

```
if myObject.prop.integerValue == MCOMessageFlag.Seen.rawValue {
    myObject.prop = NSNumber(integer: MCOMessageFlag.None.rawValue)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although Rob's answer worked I thought I should post this too. I also posted the question the the Apple Dev Forums and received a response from Chris Lattner.

> As of swift 2, option sets are now set-like, which means you cannot invert them with ~

So instead of `intersect()` I can use `subtractInPlace()`.